# adding score to a set of buttons for a quiz

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make a scoring system for my multiple choice quiz, but sometimes the score doesn't add when I click the correct answer, or it adds when I click the wrong answer.

Form 1 arrays the questions and answers and creates a randomizer

```
Public Class Form1
    Public StudentName As String
    Public Formclass As String
    Public questions(19) As String
    Public answers(19) As String
    Public x As Integer
    Public rn As New Random


    Public Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Questions
        questions(0) = "What is the biggest win in soccer"
        questions(1) = "What colour is Real Madrid's 2017-2018 season away kit"
        questions(2) = "Neymar Plays for PSG" 'T/F
        questions(3) = "What year did Manchester United sign Robin Van Persie"

        'Answers
        answers(0) = "31-0"
        answers(1) = "Black"
        answers(2) = "True"
        answers(3) = "2012"

    End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        StudentName = txtName.Text
        Formclass = txtForm.Text
        x = (rn.Next(0, 19))
        Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = questions(x)
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
```

Form 2 is the bulk of my code where i set the questions and where my score should be calculated. I did it in a way where if the the text box = a question i set in form one specific set of answers should be shown and if a certain question is shown then a specific set of answers should display on each button with one button being the answer.

```
Public Class Form2
    Public Score As Integer
    Public Answered As Integer
    Public Correct As Integer
    Public Percent As Integer
    Public Grade As String
    Public Message As String

    Sub fillanswers()


        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(0) Then
            Button1.Text = Form1.answers(0)
            Button2.Text = "41-3"
            Button3.Text = "7-0"
            Button4.Text = "27-2"



        ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(1) Then
            Button1.Text = "Pink"
            Button2.Text = "Grey"
            Button3.Text = Form1.answers(1)
            Button4.Text = "White"

        ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(2) Then
            Button1.Text = Form1.answers(2)
            Button2.Text = "False"
            Button3.Text = ""
            Button4.Text = ""

        ElseIf RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(3) Then
            Button1.Text = "2009"
            Button2.Text = "2010"
            Button3.Text = "2011"
            Button4.Text = Form1.answers(3)     

        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        fillanswers()
        Score = 0
        Answered = 0
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        fillanswers()
        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(12) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(8) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(3) Then
            Score = Score + 1
            Label1score.Text = Score
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        fillanswers()
        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(0) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(2) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(6) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(7) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(9) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(13) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(14) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(18) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(19) Then
            Score = Score + 1
            Label1score.Text = Score
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        fillanswers()
        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(4) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(2) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(15) Then
            Score = Score + 1
            Label1score.Text = Score
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ChangeQuestion()
        fillanswers()
        If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(1) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(5) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(10) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(16) Then
            Score = Score + 1
            Label1score.Text = Score
        End If



    End Sub

    Sub ChangeQuestion()
        Form1.x = (Form1.rn.Next(0, 19))
        RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(Form1.x)
    End Sub
```

Comment: There's way too much code there.  If you haven't narrowed it down more then you haven't spent enough time on the problem.  One of the characteristics of a good question is that it includes a [MINIMAL, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. You may even find that creating a simpler example makes the issue far more obvious to you and you can fix it yourself. Creating a simple test project that isolates the problem is often one of the most important step in diagnosing an issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I deleted irrelevant code to the issue, also the button click subs are the same with just different numbers for number questions.

Comment: I started reading your code and soon got sick of trying to keep track of what names like `RichTextBox1` and `Button1` were actually referring to.  Code that doesn't use descriptive names for pretty much everything is bad code.  It's often no big deal for someone to read it when they have just written it but for anyone new or even for the author coming back later, it's a right royal pain.

Comment: Richtextbox1 is just the text box that displays the question and button1 button2 button3 button4 are just the 4 multiple choice buttons you click.

Comment: I'm not interested in you telling me what they're for.  I'm interested in reading code that is written properly, which means ALL variables have descriptive names.  I shouldn't have to read "RichTextBox1" and then ask myself what you told it was for because the name itself should tell me.  I won't be reading the code unless it is edited to do that.  You shouldn't writing code that doesn't do that in the first place.

Comment: So you know what it means but you refuse to understand, I think that's your problem not mine, yeah I know I made a mistake buts its quite simple to identify  'if text box = question 1' pretty self explanatory

Comment: You should do more research on basics of programming. Like data structures in general, Class, Collection/ICollection (List and  Dictionary)

Comment: I just picked up programming so yeah Im aware

Comment: It's not a case of refusing to understand but rather a matter of how much effort we are prepared to and should have to put in to help you and how much effort you are prepared to and should have to put in to help us help you.  I could have worked out your issue from the code you first posted but I shouldn't have to waste time and effort wading through irrelevant code when you can omit it.  I also shouldn't have to waste time translating generic control names to something meaningful when you could just use meaningful names in the first place.  Some people will waste that time.  I won't.

Comment: It comes to the fact that, in my opinion, if you're going to post a question then you should do all you can to help us help you.  Using meaningful variable names in your code is an integral part of that but you should be doing it for you anyway, even if no one else would ever read your code.  It's just part of good practice.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm sorry to say this, but you need to make allowances for novice programmers. While I respect your knowledge, sometimes I think you can come across as quite abrasive in the way you word things. Telling people how negatively you feel about their current best efforts and what you refuse to do to help isn't constructive. It would be far better to either offer constructive advice about naming and naming conventions. Criticizing a novice programmer doesn't encourage them to become better. It encourages them to stop.

Answer (score 0):

referring to my last comment, it would be very helpful if you could rename your controls to have meaningful names as jmcilhinney suggested. It will make it far easier for us to understand your code.

There are a few possibilities why you're having a problem and one of them is this.

I'm guessing that when you click button2, you want to check the text that the user has entered against a question. The problem is that the order of your code may be wrong. You should be checking the answer before you change the question and answers - like this.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(4) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(2) Or RichTextBox1.Text = Form1.questions(15) Then
        Score = Score + 1
        Label1score.Text = Score
    End If
    ChangeQuestion()
    fillanswers()
End Sub
```

However, I would suggest thinking about things in an object-oriented way. For example, your code stores each question and each correct answer in separate objects (two arrays), a much better approach would be to create a question class which has the properties of a question, a correct answer and up to 3 incorrect answers. This way, the relevant bits of information are linked together and easier to deal with ..

Comment: thank you man, this seems to have worked. If im not asking for too much do have a an idea on how I could make it so that the same question does not appear twice?

Comment: To be honest, I'd re-write it using using a question class as I mentioned above. Then, for each question session, create another list and pick a question at random from the list, show the question, and after the question has been asked, remove it from that 2nd list and pick a random question again from those that remain, and so on. But if you want to keep your code as it is, you could create another array that holds the boolean and alter it after the question has been answered. When you next change the question, check the array of booleans to make sure it hasn't been asked yet.